# SQL Constraint/Check on Join tables

Tags: sql, constraints

I have three tables: `store`, `product`, `storeproduct`.

It doesn't really matter what's in the `store` and the `product` table, just know there is a `storeID` in the `store` table, and a `productID` in the `product` table. However the `storeproduct` table keeps track of the different `product`s each `store` has. So the `storeproduct` table has two columns. The `storeID` column, and the `productID` column, both foreign keys from the `store` and the `product` table.

Is there a way to put a constraint or check on any of the table to make sure that a store must have more than 0 products, and less than 50 products.

Note: I do not want a `select` statement to do this. I just want to know if there is a way to put a constraint or a check when creating the tables.

The point of this is so a user cannot `insert` into the `storeproduct` table if there are already 50 products(rows) with the same `storeID`, or `delete` from the `storeproduct` table if deleting a row will cause the last row with that `storeID` to be gone.

The `storeproduct` table might look like this

```
storeID productID
1       1
1       2
1       3
2       4
2       5
2       6
2       7
3       4
3       2
3       6
3       1
3       8
```

Comment: The short answer is no, you'll have to use a trigger.

Comment: Understanding this may just be a mental exercise; I wouldn't recommend it even if you could.  What happens when the client/user/you (we'll go with "you") want to restrict one product to only be in 10 stores?  Or a store has 50 products and a vendor ships an entirely new product to you by mistake?  Better to have a lookup table of limits by store/product and have "soft" validation asking the user "Are you sure?" when they are about to cross your arbitrary thresholds.  If there are 51 products at the store; you don't want #51 to get "lost".

Comment: thanks for the inputs so far. ya i didn't think it would be a good idea. i spent a great deal of time searching for samples/solutions, and it seems like there is nothing on it which might mean a good reason for that. i just wanted to make sure it wasn't possible before i move on to other approaches.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, depending on your database you may be able to do this.
Oracle (and maybe others) provide materialized views which you can apply constraints to.  So you could create the MV with a column PRODUCTS_IN_STORES (being something like `select storeID, count(*) as PRODUCTS_IN_STORES from stores left outer join storeproduct on store.storeid=storeproduct.storeid group by store.storeid` .Then put a constraint on it asserting that PRODUCTS_IN_STORES is between 0 and 50 or whatever.

http://www.sqlsnippets.com/en/topic-12896.html

and

http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:21389386132607

Not a complete answer for you, but something to think about and hopefully set you on your way.